# Color points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with 17 colors, there is an axis parallel rectangle whose corner points have the same color

Tags: geometry, analysis

Color points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with 17 colors, there is an axis parallel rectangle whose corner points have the same color

> We color every point in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with one of 17 different
>   colors. Show that there exists a rectangle which has sides parallel to
>   the axes and has corner points with the same color.

I have the feeling that it has to do with the Pidgeonhole Principle.

My attempt:
I start from let's say the origin and go 18 steps straigt up. Then there must be at least two points with the same color in this interval because there are only 17 different colors total. I pick those two points. Then I go from one of the points to the right at least 18 steps and in this interval by the same argument as above must be another point with the same color. Now I have three points with the same color, but how can I get the fourth one?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** As you said if you draw 18 horisontal lines, at least two points of the intersection with the $y$-axis have the same color.

Next draw the same 18 horisontal lines and many (i.e. you will figure out exactly how many you need) vertical lines. Each vertical lines intersects the 18 horisontal lines in two points of the same color. Look at these points, how many different possibilities you have? What if you have more choices than possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

If we consider $18$ points with the same $y$-coordinate and consecutive $x$-coordinates, at least $2$ of these points have the same color. There are $\binom{18}{2}$ places at which the first repetition may occur and $17$ possible colors. It follows that any rectangle $18\times\left[17\cdot\binom{18}{2}\color{red}{+1}\right]$ contains a rectangle with vertices of the same color and sides parallel to the axis, since the same configuration for the same color has to occur at least twice.